# Jobs that start on H4 EAD and can sponsor an H1B visa in the long term

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa, indian-citizens, h4-visa

What jobs can I pursue on an H4 EAD that will lead to an H1B sponsorship in the long term?

My motivation for getting a job is to support my family in the US from an immigration standpoint. My husband has been in the US on a visa since the early 2010s, and his I-140 was approved in the late 2010s. He recently had a layoff while on an H1B visa, and our family's immigration status has become uncertain. We have had to search for jobs and consider a plan B to move back to India. If this happens again in the future and I have an H1B, then he can at least stay as a dependent while searching for another job.

My background:

I have a Bachelor's in Commerce from India, but no math background. I then worked in Banking operations for seven years before moving to the US, where I was not working for five years. Last year, I worked as a Treasurer for a non-profit.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the jobs that I can go for on H4 EAD that'll get H1B sponsorship in the long term?

Any job that qualifies for H1b sponsorship. Whether the employer is *interested* in sponsoring your H1b is up to the employer. Generally employers would ask before proceeding with an offer whether you might need visa sponsorship currently or in the future. If you're asked whether you have *unrestricted* right to work in the US - you cannot say yes, because you do not currently have unrestricted right.